# File upload support in Google Dashboard

Tags: google-visualization, dashboard

After some search on the internet i was unable to find a module where we can upload file to the database using Google Dashboard. Or in simple is there any built in support for users to upload a CSV/Excel/SQL etc as data source file for Google Dashboard.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused -- Google Dashboard just displays your account information. What database are you using? Are you using BigQuery? The BigQuery Web UI (http://bigquery.cloud.google.com) has the ability to upload data from CSV files, if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: nope i am not using Big Query, but some thing similar, in google Dash Board API, or any other GOOGLE(from that i mean only GOOGLE API) that may integrate and provide almost same support.

Comment: i want to have ability to upload data to database, and for that i am looking for Builtin support more or less like an ETL tool, although i can use server side scripting language to do the same task but i am looking for a built in help

Comment: You might consider Fusion tables. https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en. But I'm still not sure what you're asking for.